# convert a 2D numpy matrix to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Certain functions in Numpy return a 2d matrix as output. but I want them to be in 2d array form.
What is the most efficient (memory and cpu) way to convert a 2d matrix to a 2d array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that a [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) is already an `ndarray` subclass, and nothing more than a specialized 2D array. Hence you're most likely quite alright without converting your matrix to an explicit `numpy.array` unless you have a particular reason to do so, perhaps the additional generality of a Numpy array.

Should this be the case, you can convert your matrix to an array with [`numpy.asarray()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html). It's important you use this method and not [`numpy.asanyarray()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html#numpy.asanyarray) in your case as with `numpy.asanyarray()` allows subclasses of `ndarray` to pass through, as your matrix would.